# Set caret position in IE9 on character removing after formatting value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caret

In the application I have an input with formatting input data and validation. All these processes hang on `input` event listener. There is some other logic on `input` event, so I wouldn't to change it to another one. But some issue exists.

When add characters to input -- position setting works well, but when I start to remove it, after each pressing backspace/delete caret moves to begin of the line.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adx788v8/)

Code snippet:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('input');
elem.addEventListener('input', function(){
 format(elem);
  set(elem, 5);
})

function format(element) {
 element.value = element.value.split(' ').join('').replace(/\B(?=(.{3})+\b)/g, " ");
}

// `set` method from https://github.com/kudago/caret-position
function set(input, start, end) {
 if (end === undefined) { end = start; }

 if (input.setSelectionRange) {
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
 } else {
  var range = input.createTextRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  range.moveEnd('character', start);
  range.moveStart('character', end);
  range.select();
 }
};

// modified https://github.com/buzinas/ie9-oninput-polyfill
(function (doc) {
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 9') === -1) return;
  var elements = [], values = [];

  doc.addEventListener('selectionchange', function(e) {
    var activeElement = doc.activeElement;

    if (activeElement.tagName === 'TEXTAREA' || (activeElement.tagName === 'INPUT' && activeElement.type === 'text')) {
      var index = elements.indexOf(activeElement),
        element = elements[index] || elements.push(activeElement);
      if (element.value !== values[index]) {
        var event = doc.createEvent('CustomEvent');
        event.initCustomEvent('input', true, true, undefined);
        values[index] = element.value;
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    }
  });
})(document);
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button, as I mentioned earlier) to create a *runnable* [mcve] would be even better, but the content is in the question now.